# Coordination of mechanical and electrical power in electric drives

Tags: control-system, efficiency, torque, velocity

I want to ask a question to respected specialists in electric drives.
It is known that the mechanical power of an electric motor is determined by a simple formula:

\${P_{mech}}= M {\omega}\$;

Electric power is determined by the basic ratio, as the product of current and voltage (if, to a first approximation, the properties of alternating current machines, etc. are not taken into account):

\${P_{el}}= U I\$;

The ratio between these powers depends on many factors (losses in the steel of the stator, rotor, losses in the converter, etc.).

Suppose we have a low-speed torque motor (in a gearless electric drive) with a torque of \$100 Nm\$ and a rotation speed of \$0.1 rad/s\$. Mechanical power of the motor will be \${P_{mech}}= 100*0.1\$;

In order to have a high efficiency of, say, \$90\$%, we must have an electric power of \$10/0.9 = 11.1 Wt\$.

Therefore, our product \$UI\$ should be equal (to a first approximation) \$11.1 Wt\$.

This means that we must have:

1) a relatively high voltage and at the same time a very small current;

2) a relatively high current and at the same time a very small voltage;

3) voltage = current;

In all three cases, we risk not providing the required high torque (which depends on both the current and voltage), therefore, we must significantly increase the current and voltage. But then the electric power will increase significantly, and the efficiency will not be equal to \$90\$%, but \$10\$% - \$30\$%.

The question is this: are my arguments true and it is impossible to design a high-performance low-speed high-torque engine in this way? Or are there ways to make good coordination between electrical and low mechanical power in such gearless electric drives?

[image: i]

Comment: What is "11.1Wt"? If it is 11.1 watts then it is written "11.1 W" as per SI standard which includes a space between the number and unit symbol.

Comment: Your right, this is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In all three cases, we risk not providing the required high torque (which depends on both the current and voltage)

No, torque only depends on current. Voltage only depends on speed. In both cases, less losses.

You can think of a motor as a 'mechanical transformer', maintaining a ratio between torque and current, and between speed and voltage, the ratio of proportionality being the kv value that's often tabulated in motor specifications. It's the same value of k for both ratios. If you increase the turns on your motor winding or increase the field, both values of k change in the same way, to keep the two Mw and IV products the same, less of course losses. Energy balance is always maintained.

If you want to make a very low speed motor, then the best way is to use gearing, but from an efficiency point of view, not energy balance. Given the physical properties of copper, iron etc, it just turns out to be easier to make a high speed motor than a low speed one.

As the copper losses vary as the current squared, it's easy to let your losses rise excessively by using more current than you expected.

Comment: Is this approach true for double salient machines (switched reluctance motors, etc.)?
Let me consider the problem specifically for direct drive.

Comment: Very simplified, of course, but in order to comply with the desired electrical power, with a large current we need a small voltage. And according to Ohm’s law, I = U / R, i.e. resistance should be fantastically small.

Comment: I'm not sure that in reality high-performance direct motors (if they exist at all) are designed that way.
What then to be with motors that have electromagnetic speed gearing? What is the relation between currents and moments there and can such an motor fulfill the role of the classic “motor + mechanical gearbox” configuration?
Like this, for example:
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/b9/09/e5/9909fb276ba558/imgf0003.png

Comment: @АндрейСологубов all the details are just fluff really, the energy balance means electrical power in = mechanical power out + losses out. Imagine using superconductor with zero resistance instead of copper. Then you could get any magnetic field you liked with zero copper losses. In that motor, torque = field*current, and voltage = speed*field. It's only when you try to make a motor with resistive copper windings that losses make you think that the power relation has broken down. It hasn't, it's just more difficult to see.

Comment: I'm confused. In reality, losses are taken into account and there is no talk of any superconductors.
Back to the direct drive. We have copper windings through which current flows from the applied voltage and they heat up. The energy of the magnetic field is converted into mechanical energy.
If the mechanical power is low (high torque * very low rotation speed), it will still require a large current (to create a large torque).

Comment: From the power balance formula it follows that if we want to ensure small losses, our electric power will also be small, and since the current is large, there should be a small voltage so as not to disrupt the planned balance.
And how can a large current be produced from a small voltage? Only fantastically small resistance - this is my thought.
Otherwise, the losses should be large enough, but then the efficiency will be small.

Comment: Thus, the question is open: power balance in an energy-efficient direct torque electric drive (with an efficiency in the region of 0.9 - 0.95).

Comment: @АндрейСологубов the question is not open, but the answer is not simple. Torque depends on current, magnetic field, and motor radius. Copper windings that heat up have nothing to do with motor power, or torque, only losses. Increase the volume of copper, so size of the motor, to reduce losses. Increase the magnetic field, so cost of the magnets, to increase torque and voltage constants, so motor power throughput.

Comment: I use a reluctance motors with electromagnetic speed gearing.
They have 5-7 small teeth located at the poles of the stator. The number of teeth on the rotor is increased in comparison with the classical versions (it can be about 30-40).

Comment: Your answer seems to clarify something, but not completely.
Let's go back to the diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bLQI.jpg
Assume that Pin = Pel, and Pout = Pmech.
What is between them (Prot + PFe + Pfr,w + Paddit) = Psumm.
Thus, we get the balance formula that you talked about. We will open it:
Pel  = Pmesh + Psumm => U*I = M*w + Psumm.

Comment: The definition of Psumm is not important for us so far, so we will simply have their set value, i.e. Psumm = arbitrary constants.
And suppose that the parameters of the power supply are imposed, for example, U = 100 V.
We have a low-speed torque motor (in a gearless electric drive) with a torque of 100 Nm and a rotation speed of 0.1rad/s. Mechanical power of the motor will be Pmech = 100∗0.1.

Comment: We substitute the power balance formula and express the current.
From a physical point of view, the obtained parameters do not mean at all that we will provide the required moment, and therefore, it is necessary to design the motor in a special way. Are my arguments true?

Comment: @АндрейСологубов I am afraid I can't understand your argument, and I can't understand what it is you don't understand, so I can't help you any more. Try designing a specific motor, rather than picking arbitrary numbers. Good luck, I won't be replying.